# Laravel 5.5 Error 500 after migration to new server

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.5 after migration home page with 500 error

i has tested to use whm terminal to generate new key

```
php artisan key:generate
```

but i receive this problem

[terminal problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J8vi.png)

```
[root@cpanel38897595 public_html]# ls
```

app        cgi-bin        database                     index.php     public      routes   vendor
artisan    composer.json  error_log                    package.json  readme.md   Script   webpack.mix.js
blog       composer.lock    php.ini       resources   storage
bootstrap  config         index.html                   phpunit.xml   robots.txt  tests
[root@cpanel38897595 public_html]# php artisan key:generate

In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `admin_settings` limit 1)

In Connector.php line 70:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: Your .env file is not configured properly

Comment: Your database and databse password not set as your .env file. Set properly those to work around your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

i checked the MYSQL SERVER in my WHM

Home »Service Configuration »Service Manager

it has been deactivated i have reactivate it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are missing the configuration/miss-configured or there are cached configurations. Configure the given settings in your `.env` file and run **`php artisan config:clear`** command in your project root.

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=user_name
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: then that MySQL user doesn't even exist in that database on server. check database named `mysql`, table `user` and if that user which is in .env file exists in mysql.user table then he doesn't have permissions for your app database

Comment: You need to create and assign privileges to the user for that specific database first and then you can use that DB user account in laravel .env file.